# Spark session creation issue while upgrading to cdh 6.1

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

Currently my spark application running in CDH.5.14 with no issues.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-cdh6.1.0
```

After upgrading to 6.1.0, issue with spark session creation.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:105)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.hiveClassesArePresent(SparkSession.scala:1117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:866)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-cdh6.1.0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:368)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to a hive [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15326). As your hive jars version is not compatible with Hadoop 3.0.

I also use Cloudera-Manager, and how I fix this is to replace the relevant jars with the **CDH versions**, like `'xxx-cdh{CDH-version}'`.

Take the pom.xml for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-cdh6.2.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```